# Como fazer cálculos ao clicar no botão e colocar o resultado em outro campo

Tags: javascript

Como fazer esse formulário fazer essa conta: `((a-b)+(((a-b)*0,1)+((a-b)*0,1268))))/240`?

Eu quero que os campos "preço do imóvel" e "valor de entrada" sejam preenchidos e, depois, quando clicar em "calcular", apareça o resultado no campo "resultado".

Se (a) for igual a 1000 e (b) igual a 100 o resultado é 4,6005.
E depois que houver feito o calculo, clicar em "limpar" para limpar os campos.

- a = preço do imóvel
- b = valor de entrada
- `0,1`,  `0,1268` e `240` são valores fixos

```css
      form{
                    width: 220px;
                    height: 360px;
                    background: #002776;                
                    border-radius: 4px;                           
                    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
                    padding: 0 2% 2% 2%;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                }

                .tsmr{
                   text-align: center;
                   color: #fff; 
                   margin: 0 0 10% 0;              
                   padding: 5% 0 5% 0;
                   font-size: 20px;
                   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
                   box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
                }

                .sml{
                width: 96%;
                margin: 1% 0 4% 0;
                }
      
                #btn, #btn1{
                width: 100%;
                height: 30px;
                margin: 9% 0 0 0; 
                font-weight: bold;
                font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
                box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
                background: #fff;
                color: #000;
                border-radius: 4px;
                letter-spacing: 2px;
                border: none;
                font-size: 15px;
                cursor: pointer; 
                }

                #lbs{
                     font-size: 13px;
                     color: #fff;
                     letter-spacing: 1px;
                     font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
                     
                }

                #lbs2{
                     font-size: 13px;
                     color: #fff;
                     letter-spacing: 1px;
                     font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
                     
                }

                #lbs3{
                     font-size: 13px;
                     color: #fff;
                     letter-spacing: 1px;
                     font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
                     
                }
```

```html
               <form>

               <p class= "tsmr">SIMULADOR</p>

               <label id="lbs">PREÇO DO IMÓVEL:</label>
               <input class="sml" type="text" value="">

               <label id="lbs2">VALOR DA ENTRADA:</label>
               <input class="sml" type="text">

               <label id="lbs3">RESULTADO:</label>
               <input class="sml" type="text">

               <button id="btn" type="buttom">CALCULAR</button>
               <button id="btn1" type="buttom">LIMPAR</button>
                    
               </form>
```

Comment: não tentou nenhum código em javascript?

Comment: Caso alguma resposta lhe serviu marque-a (a melhor) como aceita, veja em https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sem botão calcular, formatando a saída com virgula**

```js
    function reset() {
      document.getElementById("idForm").reset();
    }

    function id(el) {
      return document.getElementById( el );
    }
    function total( un, qnt ) {

        if (isNaN(un) || isNaN(qnt)){
            reset();
        }

        return parseFloat(((un-qnt)+(((un-qnt)*0.1)+((un-qnt)*0.1268)))/240);
        
      
    }

    window.onload = function() {
      id('preco').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        var result = total( this.value , id('entrada').value );
        id('resultado').value = String(result.toFixed(4)).formatMoney();
      });

      id('entrada').addEventListener('keyup', function(){
        var result = total( id('preco').value , this.value );
        id('resultado').value = String(result.toFixed(4)).formatMoney();
      });
    }

    String.prototype.formatMoney = function() {
      var v = this;

      if(v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
        v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");
      }

      v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, "$1,$20");
      v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, "$1,$2");
      v = v.replace(/([\d]+)([\d]{3}),([\d]{2})$/, "$1.$2,$3");

      return v;
    };
```

```css
      form{
                    width: 220px;
                    height: 290px;
                    background: #002776;                
                    border-radius: 4px;                           
                    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
                    padding: 0 2% 2% 2%;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                }

                .tsmr{
                   text-align: center;
                   color: #fff; 
                   margin: 0 0 10% 0;              
                   padding: 5% 0 5% 0;
                   font-size: 20px;
                   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
                   box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
                }

                .sml{
                width: 96%;
                margin: 1% 0 4% 0;
                }
      
                #btn1{
                width: 100%;
                height: 30px;
                margin: 9% 0 0 0; 
                font-weight: bold;
                font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
                box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
                background: #fff;
                color: #000;
                border-radius: 4px;
                letter-spacing: 2px;
                border: none;
                font-size: 15px;
                cursor: pointer; 
                }

                #lbs{
                     font-size: 13px;
                     color: #fff;
                     letter-spacing: 1px;
                     font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
                     
                }

                #lbs2{
                     font-size: 13px;
                     color: #fff;
                     letter-spacing: 1px;
                     font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
                     
                }

                #lbs3{
                     font-size: 13px;
                     color: #fff;
                     letter-spacing: 1px;
                     font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
                     
                }
```

```html
              <form id="idForm">

               <p class= "tsmr">SIMULADOR</p>

               <label id="lbs">PREÇO DO IMÓVEL:</label>
               <input class="sml" id="preco" type="text" value="">

               <label id="lbs2">VALOR DA ENTRADA:</label>
               <input class="sml" id="entrada" type="text">

               <label id="lbs3">RESULTADO:</label>
               <input class="sml" id="resultado" type="text">
              
               <button id="btn1" type="button" onclick="reset()">LIMPAR</button>
                    
               </form>
```

---

---

> **sobre o comentário** "Como que esse script ficaria para fazer o cálculo em uma tag `<p>`?"

```js
  
//var sn = getParameterByName('pt');

//supor que sn retornado acima seja 30
var sn=30;

document.getElementById("vj2p").innerHTML = "Preço: "+sn;

document.getElementById("receptor").innerHTML = sn;

    var calculador = document.getElementById("calculador").innerHTML;
    var resultado = (sn*calculador).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("calculador").innerHTML=resultado;
```

```html
 <p id="vj2p"></p>

 <p id="receptor"></p> <p id="calculador">0.1268</p>
```

> s**obre comentário de cálculos com formato em Real R$ 1000,00 + R$ 100,00**

```js
    const v1 = 'R$ 1.000,00';
    const v2 = 'R$ 100,00';
     let val1 = v1.replace('R$','').replace(/\./gi,'').replace(/,/gi,'.');
     let val2 = v2.replace('R$','').replace(/\./gi,'').replace(/,/gi,'.');
     
    val1 = Number(val1);
    val2 = Number(val2);

    console.log((val1 + val2).toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'brl' }));
```

Comment: Boa tarde. Como que esse script ficaria para fazer o cálculo em uma tag <p>? Ex:. (<p id="receptor"></p> <p id="calculador"></p> ) O receptor recebe a variável e o calculador armazena um valor fixo (0.1268) para calcular pelo receptor. O resultado deve aparecer no calculador. Eu tentei com esse script que vc postou, mas só consegui fazer em input.

Comment: @jairoolindino, e como seria isso de o receptor (uma tag paragrafo <p>) receber uma variável? De onde viria essa variável?

Comment: A tag <p> recebe a variável de um formulário, que fica em outra página. Eu uso esse script para receber a variável:

Comment: function getParameterByName(name, url) {
        if (!url) url = window.location.href;
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
        var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
        results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
        }

        var sn = getParameterByName('pt');

        document.getElementById("vj2p").innerHTML = "Preço: "+sn;

Comment: A página que envia a variável usa esse script: <form action="destino.html" method="GET"></form>

Comment: @jairoolindino, meio confuso, era <p id="receptor"></p> <p id="calculador"></p> e agora entra um novo getElementById("vj2p").  Melhor formular uma pergunta com os devidos códigos. De qualquer forma no final da resposta acrescentei alguma coisa para ver se é isso.

Comment: Bom dia, Leo! Consegui com o código que vc postou. ficou desse jeito: window.onload = function() {        
  var sn= 0.1268;  
        var calculador = document.getElementById("vj2p2").innerHTML;
        var resultado = (sn*calculador).toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'brl' });
        document.getElementById("vj2p3").innerHTML=resultado;
        }

Comment: Leo, vc sabe se é possível fazer cálculo utilizando formato de moeda? Ex.: R$ 1.000,00 + R$ 100,00

Comment: @jairoolindino, cálculos matemáticos somente no formato americano. Você tem que destacar e transformar a parte numérica em formato americano, realizar a operação e depois formatar brasileira para apresentar na tela.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver isso com Javascript puro, segue o código que eu escrevi pra te ajudar.

Ps.: HTML e CSS são os seus originais, só adicionei o Javascript. Clica em **Executar** no final do código.

```js
var calcButton = document.querySelector('#btn');
calcButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  var a = document.querySelector('#lbs + input').value;
  var b = document.querySelector('#lbs2 + input').value;
  if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) alert('Insira apenas números')
  if (a && b && !(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b))) {
    var inputResult = document.querySelector('#lbs3 + input');
    var rawResult =  ((a-b)+(((a-b)*0.1)+((a-b)*0.1268)))/240
    var result = rawResult.toFixed(4)
  inputResult.value = result
  }
});

var cleanButton = document.querySelector('#btn1');
cleanButton.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
    document.querySelector('#lbs + input').value = ''
    document.querySelector('#lbs2 + input').value = ''
    document.querySelector('#lbs3 + input').value = ''
});
```

```css
form {
  width: 220px;
  height: 360px;
  background: #002776;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 0 2% 2% 2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tsmr {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 0 10% 0;
  padding: 5% 0 5% 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.sml {
  width: 96%;
  margin: 1% 0 4% 0;
}

#btn,
#btn1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 9% 0 0 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-radius: 4px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  border: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#lbs {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;

}

#lbs2 {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;

}

#lbs3 {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;

}
```

```html
<form>

  <p class="tsmr">SIMULADOR</p>

  <label id="lbs">PREÇO DO IMÓVEL:</label>
  <input class="sml" type="text" value="">

  <label id="lbs2">VALOR DA ENTRADA:</label>
  <input class="sml" type="text">

  <label id="lbs3">RESULTADO:</label>
  <input class="sml" type="text">

  <button id="btn" type="buttom">CALCULAR</button>
  <button id="btn1" type="buttom">LIMPAR</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

A primeira coisa que eu faria é colocar um `id` em cada `input`, assim fica mais fácil encontrá-los. A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/462036/112052) acabou usando [seletores](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) como `'#lbs + input'`, para buscar o `input` que vem logo depois do respectivo `label`. Não está errado, mas se o `label` não é usado para nada, eu prefiro adicionar um `id` no `input` e buscá-lo diretamente.

E para que o `form` não seja submetido, você deve usar [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) nos botões, assim o formulário não é submetido e você permanece na mesma página. E para limpar o formulário, você pode usar [`input type="reset"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/reset), que *reseta* os campos para os valores iniciais (e como eles começam vazios, já parece ser o que você precisa). Usar um *event listener* próprio para limpar o formulário só faria sentido se os valores fossem diferentes dos iniciais.

E se quer de fato verificar se foi digitado números válidos eu sugiro usar [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

E um ponto que eu não gosto da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/462036/112052) é que ela verifica duas vezes se os valores são números:

```
if (isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) alert('Insira apenas números')
if (a && b && !(isNaN(a) || isNaN(b))) { etc...
```

Mas isso é redundante e desnecessário. Basta testar [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) uma vez para cada valor e caso não sejam números, use `return` para sair da função (ou seja, se o valor for inválido, nem executa o restante). E aproveitei para validar se o valor é maior que zero (pois não me parece fazer sentido aceitar preço negativo, por exemplo - já a entrada, entendo que pode ser zero).

Outro detalhe é que o cálculo `((a-b)+(((a-b)*0,1)+((a-b)*0,1268)))/240` pode ser simplificado. Basicamente, você está fazendo (desconsiderando a divisão por 240):

```
valor + (valor * 0.1) + (valor * 0.1268)
```

Que no fim é a mesma coisa que:

```
valor * (1 + 0.1 + 0.1268)
```

Que por fim é o mesmo que:

```
valor * 1.2268
```

Ou seja, o cálculo ficaria apenas `((a - b) * 1.2268) / 240`.

E também dei nomes melhores para as variáveis. Pode parecer um detalhe besta, mas [dar nomes melhores ajudam muito na hora de programar](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

Removi o CSS porque não interfere no algoritmo, e para deixar mais curto e focar somente no JavaScript e no HTML, que são o foco da pergunta.

Por fim,  [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) sempre retorna o valor usando o ponto como separador decimal. Mas como a pergunta dá a entender que quer usar a vírgula, então troque-o por [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```js
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let preco = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#preco').value);
    if (isNaN(preco) || preco <= 0) {
        alert('Preço deve ser um número maior que zero');
        return; // sai da função (nem precisa ler o valor da entrada porque não adianta)
    }
    let entrada = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#entrada').value);
    if (isNaN(entrada) || entrada < 0) {
        alert('Entrada deve ser um número maior ou igual a zero');
        return; // sai da função
    }
    let result = ((preco - entrada) * 1.2268) / 240;
    // usar toLocaleString, o locale 'pt-BR' (português do Brasil) usa a vírgula como separador decimal
    document.querySelector('#resultado').value = result.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { minimumFractionDigits: 4, maximumFractionDigits: 4 });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <p class="tsmr">SIMULADOR</p>
  <label id="lbs">PREÇO DO IMÓVEL:</label>
  <input id="preco" class="sml" type="text" value=""><br>
  <label id="lbs2">VALOR DA ENTRADA:</label>
  <input id="entrada" class="sml" type="text"><br>
  <label id="lbs3">RESULTADO:</label>
  <input id="resultado" class="sml" type="text"><br>
  <button id="btn" type="button">CALCULAR</button><br>
  <button id="btn1" type="reset">LIMPAR</button>
</form>
```

Também coloquei ponto-e-vírgula no final das linhas. Pode parecer "frescura", e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto e vírgula e "funciona", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los, como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [essa](/q/432960/112052) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341/112052)).